# A static site I published recently using AWS S3 is not reading the CSS files

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-development-server

I recently published a static website that I built using html, CSS and JavaScript and published it using AWS S3 Buckets. Although I'm able to view the site, its not reading any of the CSS files. My configuration in the html header element are using localhost as the local web server. This is what I have in all my HTML files. Please advise.

Below are some screenshots from AWS and code base for context:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You seem to have a reference to localhost:9000 in your html, which is probably a development server that will only work on your machine.  Try removing that prefix.  Relative paths to external CSS files should work anywhere.

Comment: Looks like you'll want to remove the whole localhost:9000/Drainleaf_Games prefix.  References to CSS files should be relative to the HTML file.

Comment: Hi Atif all the resources  like css or js should be in public  domain means allowed by s3. And there location should be a their actual llocation..rather than localhost.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Give relative local path to the .css and .jpg files without http.

Icon file should have proper size and have .ico extension to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `http://localhost:9000/DrainLeaf GAMES/` from lines 4, 5 & 6 of `Support.htm`. All `href`s should look like this: `href="CSS/support.css"`.